# Using Java 7 u21 in compile and Java 7 u13 in Run-time

Tags: java, java-7

We have a build server that has Java 7 update 21 version, for the run time environment we have configured Java 7 update 13. What are all the problems will I face by having this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will face confusion as to what differences it will make when it will make almost no difference what so ever.

If you want to be paranoid, I suggest you look at the list of bug that have been fixed since Java 7 update 13 and update 25 and this will give you an idea of what bugs might impact you.

Comment: There are many bug fixes from Update 13 to Update 21. Update 21 has more release fixes. Assuming if the developer uses any features from Update 21, then if the code goes to runtime environment (update 13). Will it throw an exception errors? what happens in this situation.